# How can I run a certain action when a taxonomy field value is removed or added?

Tags: 8, users, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I have a *user_territories* field which can have multiple values. I need to run a certain action when this field value is changed from the user entity, not when other fields are changed.

How can I write a condition for that?

I need to perform an action when taxonomy field is deleted and another action when a taxonomy field is added. How can I achieve this?
Is `hook_user_presave()` the best hook to fulfill this?

Comment: We cannot say which hook is the best hook to achieve what you described: It depends on what action you need to perform and on which entity. In any case, there isn't a best hook. Do you then need to perform an action when a taxonomy field is added/removed to the User entity, or when a value is added/removed from a taxonomy field for the User entity?

Comment: when a value is added/removed from a taxonomy field for the User entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `hook_user_presave()` is the way to go.

Here's an example for a standard field. You'll need to tweak this a bit for a taxonomy entity reference.

```
function MYMODULE_user_presave(UserBundle $user): void {
  // If the user is new, then the value hasn't changed.
  if (!$user->isNew()) {
    $field_value_current = $user->get('my_field_name')->value;
    $field_value_previous = $user->original->get('my_field_name')->value;
    if ($field_value_current !== $field_value_previous) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will check that. But how can I know the taxonomy term is deleted or added? @patrick-kenny

Comment: The value of the field changes.  If `$previous` is NULL or '' and `$current` is set, value was added. If `$previous` is set and `$current` is NULL or '', value was deleted.

Comment: That's cool. Thanks for the help.

Comment: When a taxonomy term is removed from a taxonomy reference field, the taxonomy term isn't necessarily deleted. It will be deleted when the taxonomy term is not used from any taxonomy reference field. If @RifasAli needs to know when a taxonomy term is deleted, the code needs to be different.

Comment: @apaderno Good point.  In my comment, I said "deleted" when I should have said "the value of the field was unset."

Comment: @PatrickKenny I thought too Rifas was asking for when a taxonomy term is removed from a taxonomy reference field, but then I noticed he repeated "deleted" twice. I didn't mean you misunderstood, but that probably the question is asking for hooking into a taxonomy term deletion.

Comment: I also meant the same.. to unset the value from the user entity.